# VBA to duplicate macro enabled workbook and rename each one from list

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Hi I need to duplicate a macro enabled work book multiple times and rename each duplicated workbook from a list of names on sheet in 1 column A. This is the code I've been trying but it keeps running into a

> runtime error 1004 save as of workbook object failed.

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
Sub Test2()
 
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rNames As Range, c As Range, r As Range
 
    'Current file's list of names and ids on sheet1.
    Set rNames = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
 
    'Path and name to master workbook to open for copy, saveas.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Q2\Test.xlsm")
 
    For Each c In rNames
        With wb
            .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = c.Offset(, 1).Value 'ID
 
            'Path and name for copied workbook
            .SaveAs Filename:="\Desktop\Q2\Test" & c.Value, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
        End With
 
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Next c

    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What is a sample value in `c`? Do the file names end in `.xlsm`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code with the only difference that I store the file in "C:\tmp\Test.xlsx" and have "save to" filename as "\tmp\Test" for simplicity.

It runs without error messages so please verify that your path to your desktop is correct. I for sure has no "C:\Desktop", I would expect there to be a "Users\user name" section in between "C:" and your desktop folder.

However A1 in the new file will be blank, I believe you want the new filename here. To fix this skip the "c.Offset" part and replace with "c" only. This as your c.Offset statement returns "empty".

PS! Runtime error 1004 could be if you are trying to save to a filename already used or somehow blocked for use. Hence if you are doing this over and over you would need to manually delete the files between each run, or include code to delete existing files before trying to save new once.

BR
Frank